# Assign a value to double pointer

Tags: c

I allocated memory for the r, which is a double pointer to struct.
However, When I was trying to use this variable, I got an error which is saying:

#### Error message

```
read-command.c:461:7: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   r+i = postfixToTree(postfix_string, &csPtr->nodeArray[i]);
       ^
make: *** [read-command.o] Error 1
```

#### Usage

```
r+i = postfixToTree(postfix_string, &csPtr->nodeArray[i]);
```

#### Declaration

#### Declaration

```
   int b;
    struct command** r;
    r = (struct command**) malloc(50 * sizeof(struct command*));
    for( b=0; b<50; b++){
      *(r+b)=(struct command*) malloc(50*sizeof(struct command));
    }
```

How do I assign a value to r?

Comment: What does `postfixToTree` return? Also, `r+i` is a temporary --- even if it were possible to modify it, the modification would be immediately lost. What exactly do you want to modify?

Comment: Please add the full declaration of `postfixToTree()` to the question (probably after the first `Declaration` heading.  Do you not like array subscripts?  Using `r[b] = (struct command *)malloc(50 * sizeof(struct command));` would be sensible.  Your `r+i` code should also be `r[i]` or `*(r+i)`, though doing that leaks memory (quite a lot of memory — 50 copies of a `struct command` each time you do a `postfixToTree()` call.

Comment: Your code and error message don't agree, but did you `#include <stdlib.h>`?  The cast of `malloc` may be hiding that malloc isn't declared correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?  Make sure to include `stdlib.h`, the malloc casts are not needed, and `*(r+b)` is equivalent to `r[b]`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct command {
    int x; // just a definition to compile
};

int main()
{
    int b;
    struct command** r;
    r = malloc(50 * sizeof(struct command*));
    for( b=0; b<50; b++) {
        r[b] = malloc(50*sizeof(struct command));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

General syntax of C assignment.

```
    Lvalue=Rvalue;
```

Above Rvalue can be result of an expression or function call or simply another variable of same type or constant , Lvalue is a variable that can able to store Rvalue.

```
r+i = postfixToTree(postfix_string, &csPtr->nodeArray[i]);  

^^^
```

Trying to add i value to r , in the place of `Lvalue`.

In C there should not be any evaluation part in The Left hand side.

Add first and then assign

```
  r=r+i; //r+=i; 
  r = postfixToTree(postfix_string, &csPtr->nodeArray[i]);
```

you can write above statements As below

```
  r[i] = postfixToTree(postfix_string, &csPtr->nodeArray[i]);
```

And for every time when you make a call to function `postfixToTree()`

```
for( b=0; b<50; b++)
  *(r+b)=(struct command*) malloc(50*sizeof(struct command));
```

Here you are creating `50` copies of `struct command` on `each iteration`. Doing this leaks lot of  memory.

Also `free()` the memory which is allocated with the `malloc()` inside function.

Comment: That's probably not what's wanted, and the potential for memory leaks is enormous (in the original code and in your outline solution).  Any particular reason not to use `r[i]` notation?

Comment: sorry,OP can use r[i]. There is  memory allocation in function that makes Huge memory leak.thanks for pointing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing wrong with the pointers.

Do like this,

```
 int b;
    struct command** r;
    r = (struct command**) malloc(50 * sizeof(struct command*));
    for( b=0; b<50; b++){
      *(r) + b=(struct command*) malloc(50*sizeof(struct command));
    }
```